# Indiana Jones - The explorer

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, idioms, idiom-requests

I am looking for a word that describes an explorer who travels the world in search of rare items. I'm thinking Indiana Jones, going to far off places in search of magical things...

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The first word that would come to mind for me would be adventurer.

Answer (score 5):

**Treasure hunter** would seem to fit the bill.

> A treasure hunter is a person who, as either a vocation or avocation, searches for sunken, buried, lost, or hidden treasure and other artifacts.
>
> **Historical**
>
> - Giovanni Battista Belzoni (1778–1823, Italian). sometimes known as The Great Belzoni, was a prolific Italian explorer and pioneer archaeologist of Egyptian antiquities. He removed with great skill the colossal bust of Ramesses II...
>
> **Fictional**
>
> - Jim Hawkins, the protagonist of Robert Louis Stevenson's 1881 novel, Treasure Island
> - Allan Quatermain, a hunter and adventurer, the protagonist of H. Rider Haggard's 1885 novel King Solomon's Mines
>   ...
> - Indiana Jones...

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_treasure_hunters